# ComponentDidMount Uncaught Error in Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, methods, page-lifecycle

I have a function that I need to fire in a set order so I can receive the books from the logged in user. Right now this function works partially. It doesn't work when I refresh the page. It says there's an uncaught error in the promise. I need the getBooks function to finish before the console log fires. What's the way to write this?

```
async componentDidMount() {
     this.props.getBooks({
        user: this.props.auth.user.id
    
    })

    const wishlistbooks = this.props.auth.wishlistbooks;
    console.log(`WISHLIST:${wishlistbooks[0].book.title}`)
}
```

getBooks method

```
export const getBooks = (user) => dispatch => {

    axios
        .get("/api/users/wishlist", {
            params: {
                id: user
            }
        })
  
        .then(res => {
            const response = res.data;
            dispatch(setWishlist(response));
        })

        // .then(response => {
        //     console.log(response)

        //     dispatch(setWishlist({response}))
        // })

        .catch(() =>{
            console.log("Error!")
        })
    };
    
    export const setWishlist = response => {
        console.log(response)
        return {
            type: WISHLIST_LOADING,
            payload: response
        };
    };
```

Comment: What's the details of the error?

Comment: show the getBooks method code in parent component

Comment: Error - can't read property 'book' of undefined. Just added getBooks method to question

Comment: You logged the wishlist while it is not loaded yet, just add a condition to your code `if(wishlistbooks.lenght)` for example

Comment: in then function in getbooks you have to return promise object and add await in componentdidmount function where you triggering this method, I am sure this should work. otherwise it can give you undefined data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either a) separate the triggering of the asynchronous data from the usage of that data or b) lean into the asynchronous nature of it, and wait until it's over.

In the first case, using the data (your console.log) would be handled in the `render` method. In that case, your render method would need to be able to handle renders that have no data available (e.g. render a `loading...` message or something.)

```
  render() {
    if (!this.props.auth.wishlistbooks) {
      return 'Loading...'
    }
    
    const wishlistbooks = this.props.auth.wishlistbooks;
    return <>WISHLIST: {wishlistbooks[0].book.title}
  }
```

In the second case, `await getBooks` and make sure you return the axios call from it.

```js
async componentDidMount() {
  await this.props.getBooks({ // this causes componentDidMount to wait for getBooks to complete
    user: this.props.auth.user.id
  })

  const wishlistbooks = this.props.auth.wishlistbooks;
  console.log(`WISHLIST:${wishlistbooks[0].book.title}`)
}

export const getBooks = (user) => dispatch => {
  return axios.get("/api/users/wishlist", { // returning the axios.get passes the promise back up to componentDidMount
    // ...
```

Why would you choose one or the other? The first case is more useful for rendering. If the data you're fetching is something you're relying on to display, you'll need to handle the times when you don't have it. The second case is more useful for data you're using internally only. (Perhaps it's logging or metrics or you're just testing how something works.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! The first case sounds like what I'm looking for. However, if I refresh the page then the data will not display because getBooks isn't done being called, which the current issue I'm having

Comment: The second option works well. I do want eventually display the data. Can you explain a little more why the await method isn't good for this?

Comment: `await` isn't bad, it's just not related. It won't let you display the data automatically. You'd need to `setState` afterwards to get that to happen. That's a bit goofy b/c you already have that data in props, so why set it to state? 

Looks like you're using Redux? If so, the mapStateToProps function should be updating props appropriately so that this component rerenders. If that's not happening (which it seems like it's not?) it's probable that it's mutating `props.auth` instead of replacing it with a copy. It's hard to tell without more information.